# Could I use GCP infrastructure as a code to setup Firebase Auth, Firestore, RDB, Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, infrastructure-as-code

I know that I could setup Cloud Firestore and GCP Cloud Functions with infrastructure as a code, but I'm interested that it will be shown at the Firebase Console. I also can't find any way to deploy Firebase Auth and Realtime database with IaaC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any Cloud Functions deployed by either the Firebase CLI or gcloud will appear in both the Firebase console and the Cloud console.

Any data populated in Firestore will also appear in both consoles.

The Cloud console has no view into Firebase Auth or Realtime Database, as those services are unique to Firebase.  You will have to use the Firebase console and its tools and SDKs to work with those products.

In fact, a Firebase project is just a Cloud project with extra APIs and services enabled on top.  You might be helped by reading this blog series on the relationship between Firebase and Google Cloud.

- https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f
- https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-functions-612d9e1e89cb
- https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-firestore-40f1fc3e6d1e
- https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-storage-a33fad7c2b80

Comment: Thanks for fast answer.
It is possible to somehow setup Auth and the needed provider with Firebase Cli or Rest Api? Or it's the only possibility its to do it manually with the GUI? The reason I'm asking its that I want to script or code the setup. To avoid mistakes and control the setup together with the rest of the backend.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Please file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support